# Stripe Recurring Contribution generating errors when trying to add the Contribution

Tags: contributions, recurring-contributions, stripe

I've got a strange issue with a Recurring Contribution. The Recurring Contribution (Subscription) was created in November 2021, but no Contributions were recorded on the membership record.

On the Renewal date (Nov 2022) some of the events are failing with this error: https://gist.github.com/benrfairless/523235f06c1a8b1689caa2018f8ff96a.

Re-running the errored events from the "Payment Processor Webhooks" page produces the same error.

Has anyone seen this before? And do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Has the contact been merged?  You can get problems recording subsequent contributions if the recurring contribution was set up on a contact that was later merged into another contact and deleted.  There are updates that will hopefully be released soon to address contact merging.

One way of seeing if the contact has been merged is to look at the activities of the contact.

This doesn't fix your problem but may help to clarify the cause.